# Converting int to String and then String to int array

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I've been trying to do this simple program where I need to check which digit of an integer number is the biggest one. So my initial thought was that I shall convert it all into an array and go with the for loop to check which element of an array is biggest. In order to do this I converted integer into String and then characters of the String into elements of an array. I ran into problem and I looked online for solution. What I don't understand is why do I need the " temp.charAt(i) - '0'" part in order to store characters of String as elements of the array. Why can't it be only arrTemp[i] = temp.charAt(i), without the "- '0'" part.

```
    String temp = Integer.toString(n);
    int arrTemp[] = new int[temp.length()];
    int max = arrTemp[0];
    for(int i = 0; i<temp.length(); i++) {
        arrTemp[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
```

Comment: Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) for `String.toCharArray`.  The solution you have found on the internet (?) is unnecessarily complicated.  (Remember: people who post things on the net don't necessarily know what they are talking about ...)

Comment: *"What I don't understand is why do I need the " temp.charAt(i) - '0'" part in order to store characters of String as elements of the array."* - For your purposes, you don't need to do that. What that is actually doing is converting digit characters to the corresponding values as integers; e.g. `'0'` -> `0`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`'0'` is the character `'0'`, not the integer `0`.  Characters are represented using int values (ascii code).
The ascii code for `'0'` is the integer value `48`.

`int n = (int) '0';  //n would be 48.`

So, to convert `'0'` to the integer `0`, you need to subtract `'0'-'0' = 48-48 = 0`

To convert `'9'` to int `9`:

`'9' - '0' = 57-48 = 9`

See ASCII code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 0):

In many programming languages(Java, C etc.), a character variable does not contain a character value itself rather the [ascii value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) of the character variable. The ascii value represents the character variable in numbers, and each character variable is assigned with some number range from 0 to 127(in decimal number system). For example, the ascii value of 'A' is 65 and '0' is 48.

You can convert any digit character to integer by subtracting `'0'` from that character. This subtraction between characters is possible because of ascii values.

Imagine you want to convert digit character `'9'` to an integer `9`. ASCII value of character `'9'` is `57` and ASCII value of character `'0'` is `48`. Now, if you perform a subtraction operation of characters, `'9' - '0'`, it will be treated like `57 - 48` and thus will give you a result of `9`. This subtraction operation of characters converted a character `'9'` to an Integer `9`.

Try this code example:

```java
    class Converter {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println('9'-'0'); 
        }
    }
```

You can see all of the characters points to an ascii value,
[image]